# iOS Setting Twitter Consumer Key with SLRequest for Server Side

Tags: ios, twitter, slrequest

I am using SLRequest to call on twitter from my server.

I have accomplished this by changing the url from the twitter API to the server's api calls.

This works perfectly, accept for the consumer key and secret.

From my reading, SLRequest doesn't use consumer key, but the clients server is receiving a random consumer key.

How can I set the consumer key and secret that SLRequest will send to the server?

Thanks in advance!